# App Delegate OpenUrl method is not calling when clicking on ForgotPassword link in MSAL login page (Xamarin Forms App)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal

Am using MSAL for authenticating users with Xamarin Forms. Whenever we are running the app in VS2019 xamarin iOS AppDelegate OpenUrl method is not calling when we are clicking on forgot password or signup links and login page is closing without any error throwing.

XF Version              : 4.1.0.XXXX
MS.IdentityModel.Client : 4.7.1
Calling method like below :

```
     **[Export("application:openURL:options:")]  
    [ObjCRuntime.Introduced(ObjCRuntime.PlatformName.iOS, 9, 0,objCRuntime.PlatformArchitecture.All, 
     null)]  
    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {  
         //code  
    }**
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c#ios) to config the  custom URL scheme in `info.plist` correctly?

Comment: Yes ,in VS 2017 it worked . After moving to VS 2019 we are facing issue.

Comment: Did you change any code before you changing from  VC2019 to vc2017? It should work if nothing changes except IDE.

Comment: Didn't change any code and in Android its working fine.only in iOS it's not working.

Comment: Don't have too many idea if you did not change any code. You can send a support request to the Xamarin support team at [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6) or share a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here and we will check it.